# Magento translation and url key

Tags: magento, url, seo, translation

I have a Magento website with some pages linked to main navigation.
For example, in my default view (Italian) I have www.example.com/italian-url-key
Then I created another page for English view with url www.example.com/english-url-key

So, when I am on the italian version of the page and try to switch to english version, this is the url that magento generate: http://www.example.com/italian-url-key/?___store=english&store=&___from_store=default and on click it gives me 404 page.

How can I fix it? I need that this 2 pages should be linked, also if url key is different.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box Magento does not support URL Translation, both pages need the same URL key.  Check instructions from the [Magento Docs on how to translate CMS pages.](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#cms/page-translate.html)

> To translate a CMS page, you must create a new page that has the same
>   URL Key as the original, but assigned to the specific store view.

So you will either have to stick to one languages for your URLs or develop/acquire a module to do this for you.  The [magento-language-roots](https://github.com/klein0r/magento-language-routes) or [CMSRewrites](https://github.com/tzyganu/CmsRewrites) modules both look like they will achieve this for you.

You may also want to consider adding [Hreflang tags](https://moz.com/learn/seo/hreflang-tag) to your `head.phtml` as you have a multi-lingual site.